# Bindings on ObjectController - Ember.js

Tags: binding, ember.js

When you try adding a binding to an `ObjectController` it doesn't work.

```
App.FailController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    content: null,
    myBinding: "App.router.myController" // <-- fails
});
```

#### Error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('my', ) to the 'content' property of object proxy <.FailController:ember154>: its 'content' is undefined.
```

It tries adding it to the `content` property.

jsFiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3PTpt/1/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**credits:** to [caligo-mentis](https://github.com/caligo-mentis) who [answered](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1390#issuecomment-8703178) this over at github.

`ObjectProxy` delegates any call to `set` to the `content` property unless a property with the same name exists on the `ObjectProxy` instance. The simple solution is to define a property with the desired name prior to declaring the binding.

```
App.FailController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    my: null,
    myBinding: "App.router.myController" // <-- works
});
```

jsFiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3PTpt/3/)

Comment: this works.  I don't think you have to set content: null explicitly either

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution:

```
App.FailController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    content: Ember.Object.create(),
    my: function() {
      return App.router.myController;
    }.property('App.router.myController')
});
```

or better:

```
App.FailController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    content: Ember.Object.create(),
    my: Ember.computed.alias('App.router.myController')
});
```