# Global customEvents with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'd like to have multiple views reacting to something that the user does. So I thought, a global custom event would be right thing to achieve my goal. If there's something better, I'm happy for other ideas.

According to [the documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/view_layer/#toc_adding-new-events), I should be able to add custom events to my Ember.js application like that:

```
Mobile = Em.Application.create({
  customEvents: {
    "customevent": "customevent"
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, the documentation stops there and doesn't tell me how to fire the event and bind something to it. So tried it myself and created a view that should "listen" to it:

```
Mobile.HeaderView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: "header",
  customevent: function() {
    return console.log("Custom event has been fired!");
  }
});
```

At the end, I fired the event in my console:

```
$.event.trigger("customevent")
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or if there's even a better way to get what I want?

Comment: I would say that you should trigger the event like this: $('#foo').trigger('click'); because the way you do it, is probably in a higher scope, that is why ember doesn't catch it. #foo should be a selectir within your view.

Comment: You are right, it works when I call `trigger()` on a selector within my view. But "within my view" also means it's not a global event anymore, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem using `Em.Binding` like Luke Melia demonstrates in his slides:
http://www.lukemelia.com/devblog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/

Code example [from another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502465/bindings-on-objectcontroller-ember-js):

```
App.FailController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    content: null,
    my: null,
    myBinding: "App.router.myController", // <-- works
});
```