# Ember.js: Computed property involving other controller not refreshing upon load of model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following code:

```
  App.UserController = App.EditableController.extend({
    needs: 'application',
    test: function() {
      return this.get('controller.application.me.email');
    }.property('controller.application.me.email'),
  });

  App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isPublic   : true,
    me         : null,
    init: function () {
      this.set('me', App.User.find(1));
      this._super();
    }
  });
```

But the computed property doesn't seem to update once the model loads (from the console):

```
> App.__container__.lookup('controller:Application').get('me.email')
"test@example.com"
> App.__container__.lookup('controller:User').get('test')
undefined
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `App.EditableController` is of type `Ember.ObjectController` then this should work:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'application',
  // notice the we use here plural 'controllers' to have access to the
  // controllers defined with the 'needs' API
  contentBinding: 'controllers.application',
  test: function() {
    return this.get('content.me.email');
  }.property('content')
});
```

In the case that your `App.EditableController`is of type `Ember.Controller` than this should do the job:

```
App.UserController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'application',
  // notice the we use here plural 'controllers' to have access to the
  // controllers defined with the 'needs' API
  controllerBinding: 'controllers.application',
  test: function() {
    return this.get('controller.me.email');
  }.property('controller')
});
```

Now doing `App.__container__.lookup('controller:User').get('test')` in the console should output:

```
"test@example.com" // or whatever your example mail is
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much!  `EditableController` is indeed an extension of `ObjectController`.  Why does `contentBinding` work but not `controllerBinding`?

Comment: @BrianGates I'm glad I could help. As for the `contentBinding` this is because a `ObjectController` needs it's `content` property to be defined and thus we are using it here, the simple `Controller` has not such property so it could be also `fooBinding` in that case, and then `property('foo')` accordingly

Comment: Upon further testing, using `contentBinding` seems to clobber the existing `content` property (which makes sense), but if I use any other value, I get an error `Assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('foo', <App.ApplicationController:ember368>) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.UserController:ember369>: its 'content' is undefined.`  Doing a little research, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502465/bindings-on-objectcontroller-ember-js. So all I have to do is declare a `controller` property, then I can actually use `controllerBinding`.